# Compiling and Linking DirectX on MinGW

Tags: c, mingw, directx, ld

I am looking to develop a d3d11 app with gcc from tdm-gcc(tried pure MinGW didn't work), I've written test app, but am unable to link libd3d11 in order to get D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48
The app is supposed to be compileable in both 32-bit and 64-bit respectively.
Here's how I compile trying to use mingw headers and libs:

```
gcc -m32 -ld3d11 main.c -o test.exe
```

I am getting:

```
C:/MinGW/64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\TEMP\ccvsC3nh.o:main.c:(.text+0x243): undefined reference to `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've seen some posts about compiling directx via mingw, but they didn't give sufficient info, as I am not exactly sure what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: In your code, do you write D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48 or D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain?

Comment: I write D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain, for 64-bit it will be D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain, for 32-bit it will be D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48.

Comment: Can you try with a more recent GCC/MinGW-w64 like 10.2.0 from http://winlibs.com/ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zig creates a C library but not usable by C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65187214/zig-creates-a-c-library-but-not-usable-by-c)

Comment: @BrechtSanders everything went the same

Comment: OH WHAT IT ACTUALLY WORKED

Comment: @eLeCtrOssSnake Was this with the compiler from http://winlibs.com/ ?

Comment: it damn crashes after executing d3d11 functions... uh something's wrong...

Comment: @BrechtSanders No it was with tdm-gcc

Comment: Nvm, I was stupid a bit, everything is flying as intended.
Incorrect argument order was the only problem.